# Change on hover properties if condition is true

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

So I'm making a web app using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and AngularJS.
So far, I have a box with some content in the box. When that box is clicked, I call a javascript function to display more boxes and I did that using ng-click.

```
<div ng-click="!(clickEnabled)||myFunction(app)" class ="box">
   *** things displyaed inside the box ***        

</div>
```

clickEnabled's value (true or false) determines if myFunction() gets called or not and this part works perfectly. ng-click is disabled when clickEnabled is false. 
Now the problem is that in my css file, I have my .box class such that the cursor is pointer when I hover over the box and background of the box also changes on hover. Is there a way to make cursor:default and make it so that it doesn't change background color of box when ng-click is disabled or when clickEnabled is false?

Here's a sample of my css code

```
     .box {
          border: 1px solid lightgray;
          padding: 10px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          border-color: white;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
          cursor: pointer;
          background: #353131;
          border-width: 2px;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 300px;
          height: 150px;
    }

   .box:hover {
       background-color: dimgrey;
       border-color: grey;
    }
```

Again, I don't want the cursor to be pointer when clickEnabled is `false/ng-click` is `disabled`.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `ng-class`

```
<div ng-click="!(clickEnabled)||myFunction(app)" ng-class="{no-cursor: !clickEnabled}" class="box" >
   *** things displyaed inside the box ***        

</div> 

.box.no-cursor {
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't know it was this simple. Thank you so much :)